# How to listen for SwitchPreferenceCompat to change

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add a onCLick listener to my switch on my PreferenceScreen but it isn't working. I had tried the code from a java tutorial and converted it to Kotlin but for some reason it isn't working.

Here is my AdbSettingsFragment:

```
package com.wrssmithjr04.systemuituner

import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.preference.Preference
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat


class AdbSettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    private val key1 = "adb_switch"

    private var preferenceChangeListener: OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener? = null

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.adb_prefs, rootKey)

        preferenceChangeListener =
            OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key ->
                if (rootKey == key1) {
                    Log.d("Test", rootKey)
                    val adbPref = findPreference<Preference>(key)
                    // Doesn't get to this part
                    Log.d("Test", key1 + "was pressed")
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener)
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure `rootKey == key1` returns true? Add `Log.d` with some message before the if statement.

Comment: One more question `// Doesn't get to this part` means it gets to `val adbPref = findPreference<Preference>(key)` and crashes?

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I addad `Log.d("Test", key)` before the if statement and it returns adb_switch. Also i was saying it didnt get to `Log.d("Test", rootKey)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why do you check the equality of `key1` with the `rootKey`. However, it's a better pattern to check the type of preference first (causes implicit smart casting), then check its key:

```
preferenceChangeListener = OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key ->
    val preference = findPreference<Preference>(key)
    when (preference) {
        is SwitchPreferenceCompat -> {
            if (key == "adb_switch") {
                Log.d("Test", "${preference.key} : ${preference.isChecked}")
            }
        }
        is CheckBoxPreference -> {
            // do sth else
        }
        is ListPreference -> {
            // do sth else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have an error on `findPreference(key)` it says `Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in 

fun <T : Preference!> findPreference
(
key: CharSequence
)
: T?
Please specify it explicitly.`

Comment: change it with `findPreference<Preference>(key)` as you did in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit your if statement. Root key is most likely not the variable you want to compare against, but instead use `key` and `key1`:

```
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key ->
    if (key == key1) {
        Log.d("Test", rootKey ?: "root key is null")
        val adbPref = findPreference<Preference>(key)
        Log.d("Test", key1 + "was pressed")
    }
}
```